# Combine different rows and then sum the values

Tags: pandas

how to merge the two rows, sum the values?

Exemple:

[image]

I need to merge these two rows that are in red. Would be the solution?

I have seen some solutions to concatenate and merge but none of them meet the result

The expectation is to merge the lines with the values, keeping the name Tatuí

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pandas` `groupby` function. This will group by the location name column and sum the remaining numeric columns.

You can read the official documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

```
df.groupby(['locationName'], as_index=False).sum()
```